# How to install matplotlib and pyparsing correctly on OSX-Lion?

Tags: qgis-plugins, mac, matplotlib

I am trying to install the Contour plugin in QGIS 2.0.1 (I'm running OSX-Lion) and I have installed NumPy and Matplotlib from kyngchaos however when I go to install the plugin I get the following error:

> The Plugin is broken. Python said:
>   matplotlib requires pyparsing

Did I misinstall matplotlib or do I simply need to find a copy of pyparsing, and if so, where is a good place to get it?

UPDATE:
I downloaded pyparsing from pyparsing.wikispaces.com and have been following the guidelines for installation. The README tell me to "Do the usual: python setup.py install" but the online instructions say to use "easy_install pyparsing". I am not sure what I am really supposed to do with this information. I have tried running the "Setup.py" file but it lacks a command but I am not sure where to add the command.

Thanks
DF

Comment: This isn't really a GIS question (I know you are trying to use QGIS, but that isn't the issue here), and would be better asked on a macos or python related list. I can say that it looks like you may need to use the command line (terminal in macos) to follow the instructions you appear to be looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QGIS use the Apple Python installed by default on your system and [pyparsing](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyparsing) is a Python module.

And even if it is not a GIS question, to install a Python module (if you have not [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) or [easy_install](https://wiki.python.org/moin/EasyInstall)):

1. download the module and unzip it
2. open the Terminal.app and cd to the folder of the unzipped module
3. type:

   python setup.py install

and pyparsing is installed in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it installing pyparsing by going to Terminal and typing: `sudo /usr/bin/easy_install pyparsing`, which uses the `easy_install` that comes with the Apple-supplied Python version that QGIS is using.